# What is "charge dumping"?

Tags: amplifier

In the datasheet of the [Texas Instrument AMC1200](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1200.pdf) isolated amplifier the mention that C3 and C4 can be used to reduce "charge dumping".

What is meant by charge dumping? How useful are C3 and C4 in this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They "smooth" voltage transients, but they do act also like low pass filter among with already present R2,R3,C2. Now you add a LPF with R2-C4 and R3-C3. These two filter have to be identical, the resistors and C3,C4 need to have small tolerance.

The main purpose is to limit dv/dt on the inputs of the amplifier.

EDIT:
Common mode noise in differential probe: [EEvblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/new-low-cost-($170)-100mhz-differential-scope-probe-from-micsig/125/) showing signal artefact of square pulse due to gain/filter mismatch of positive VS. negative signal.

[image]

Comment: So it would only be for transient damping at VINP, however due to the differential input it must be duplicated on VINN?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Exactly, if those components are different, then you will get a common mode noise, when the shunt current will change you get some nasty output. You'd better to design them and leave unpopulated if you see bad results.